# Deleting html spaces, using css

Tags: html, css

This is css code:

```
#div_0, #div_1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#div_0 {
    background-color: #090;
}

#div_1 {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

and this is HTMl

```
<div id="div_0"></div>
<div id="div_1"></div>
```

this displayd so:
http://jsfiddle.net/7G63S/

As you see, here is spice between div tags, for delete this space I can write html so:

```
 <div id="div_0"></div><div id="div_1"></div>
```

and problem resolved:
http://jsfiddle.net/7yE2M/

But intereset, how can delete space between divs with css, if html look like so:

```
<div id="div_0"></div>
<div id="div_1"></div>
```

?

or make this impossible ?

P.S.  **white-space: nowrap** not helps in this case.

Comment: You can't delete, using CSS – you could only hide…

Answer (score 5):

Set `line-height` and `font-size` to 0 on the wrapping container - see http://jsfiddle.net/7G63S/1/

Comment: yeahh thats the right approach for this instead of @sowmya answer

Comment: Note that this isn't very SEO-friendly. Web crawlers might consider this abuse since you are explicitly hiding text; of course this CSS rule will be probably overridden by rules in children, but I still think this isn't a great idea.

Comment: @Abody97 - I would hope that web crawlers would not the amount non-whitespace text being hidden by this technique (in this case, none) and not penalize a website that uses this technique.

Comment: @SeanVieira Yeah, because I can't think of a cleaner solution.

Comment: If you're working with ems, this solution has horrible side effects... like not being able to reset the font-size of the child elements using ems.

Comment: @cimmanon - you can target the child containers and reset *their* `font-size` - e. g. `.my-container div { font-size: 16px; }` and then use `em`s to your heart's content.

Comment: @Sean Vieira except for the part where you aren't using ems anymore, as in all font-sizes are measured in ems.  Resetting it to a px value is not the same thing.

Comment: @cimmanon - you are just resetting the container to your base `font-size` - the same size you are setting presumably on the `body` tag - and if you are using a CSS pre-processor like LESS or SASS or if you set all of your reset points `font-size` in the same place (i.e. `body, .my-container div { font-size: 16px; }` you can use `em`s everywhere else you want to and get proper re-sizing behaviors without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `float:left` style to the divs `#div_0, #div_`

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/7yE2M/1/

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem but is a completely different approach to position elements in the layout…

Comment: @krish Only that `float: left;` isn't inline-block.

Comment: yeahh thats the wrong approch.  @sean vieira done in a right way

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the whitespace for source formatting reasons or is this a case of being unable to modify some generated HTML?  If you can modify the html, your best bet is to simply eliminate the whitespace, but that doesn't have to mean you need to lose your formatting.  Just comment out the whitespace:

```
<div id="div_0"></div><!--
--><div id="div_1"></div>
```

Edit:  more solutions can be found here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/